# AngularJS 1.5 components in tables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

With the release of AngularJS 1.5, I thought it would be a good idea to break up my existing application to use the new Component-based Architecture they're advocating.

I was able to convert most of my application to components, but I ran into a problem when trying to split up a table.  I decided that it made sense for each table row to be a separate component, because each row has specific formatting controlled by the data (the app is for displaying logs, and each row is color-coded and possibly faded out depending on the filter settings and the contents of the row).  However, I've run into a problem with custom elements not working inside of tables.

I know with directives you can simply change it to an attribute directive and apply it to a table row element, but that option doesn't appear to be available for the new components.  Additionally, I didn't particularly like that solution, as the directive/component needs to apply a class to the table row for the formatting.  It's much cleaner to do that if the row is declared in the template rather than as the enclosing element.

I also found an archaic "replace" parameter which looks like it would have been perfect for this use case, but unfortunately that was deprecated and removed two major versions ago.  I unfortunately wasn't able to find a substitute for that functionality.

Is there a good way to make the new components work inside of tables?  And if not, is there another way to accomplish what I want to do without resorting to an attribute directive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290332/angular-component-no-template-replace-option