# Angular Component: no template replace option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, components

It looks like there is no "replace" option in new [AngularJS 1.5](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) Component concept (like it was for directives).

What would you suggest if I want to have **table row** `<TR>` element as component? Is it not possible in terms of valid HTML?

Real example: mailBox component has mail components inside. By markup mail-box-component is table, and mail-box is tr.

```
<mail-box>
    <mail ng-repeat="mail in $ctrl.mails" mail="mail"></mail>
<mail-box>
```

---

**UPD**: related discussion about directives - [Why is replace deprecated in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs)

Comment: The solution is to not use markup and CSS with strict structural requirements. What does `mail` do exactly? Most likely mailbox has to absorb its functionality and the whole template.

Comment: I want each mail be the separate component

Comment: That's the work for directives, not components. Components are meant to be self-contained UI widgets, read more on Web Components.

Comment: @estus though I generally agree with the sentiment, that's not necessarily true, think of the option element that doesn't stand alone without a select element around it

Comment: Don't use `tr`. Problem solved. A list of mails is not tabular data, so using `table` is semantically wrong anyway.

Comment: @abetteroliver what is tabular data if not comparable sets of data of the same types that would be more clearly represented in a grid? No, email inboxes don't always/often use a grid layout, but sender, timestamp, subject, summary definitely fit most people's understanding of tabular data.

Comment: @maurice _"The <table> HTML element represents tabular data — that is, information presented in a two-dimensional table comprised of rows and columns of cells containing data."_ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) _"tabular: of, relating to, or arranged in a table
specifically : set up in rows and columns"_ _"No, email inboxes don't always/often use a grid layout"_ If it's not stored as a table and not presented as a table, it is not a table.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not possible the-angular-way anymore since the replace: true flag has been deprecated

[Why is replace deprecated in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs?lq=1)

the replace: true flag had come up with more problems than solutions which is why it was removed.
therefore you can not build directives in such a way anymore and provide valid table-tr-td markup.

However, there are two reasons why this is not as bad as it looks:

1. you can do everything you want to do without table, tr, td, etc.
   just using elements like div, span, etc. and some css on it
2. web-components (and directives were a first attempt to simulate
   them) are not meant to represent such small fragments of the markup.
   they are more thought of as a fully functional component actually
   doing something. so whatever you want to do with your tr that you
   think it's worth building an element-directive around it, it
   probably isnt.

Maybe, what you can do is using an attribute-directive instead:

```
<tr my-mail-directive></tr>
```

and your my-mail-directive does the magic on the tr element

Comment: Attributes are also not possible for components, if I understand the docs correctly. "restrict: No (restricted to elements only)"

Comment: @PatrickKelleter the wording you are using only causes confusion. Components are NOT directives, directives ARE NOT part of Angular2 plain and simple, to say a component is a directive only confuses people

Comment: @BrianOgden
what i said is that the OLD elment-directives (ng1, restrict:' E') are now known as components in ng2 - while the OLD attribute-directives (ng1, restrict: 'A') are not known as directives in ng2. and YES - there ARE directives in ng2. saying that directives are not part of ng2 is wrong - plain and simple.
check out the documentation for it
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: I must say I moved back to a table/tr/td setup for a page where I needed .... a table :). Any it works quiet nice to define the width once in the TH and all TD's follow suit. I find that still harder to do with Divs. You have to use a bit more CSS magic I guess.

Comment: **There are directives in angular 2** just so that's redundantly clear.

Comment: When you print a page, a browser repeats the thead on the top of all pages.  How do you achieve that with divs?

Comment: @nawlbergs without checking, I'd say changing the display property of an element to thead should make it behave like a thead. It's just a bit more complicated to simulate tables using other element as you'll have to replicate display properties of the td/tr/thead/tbody/table.